# NFS connection won't mount in Dolphin

Tags: fedora, nfs, dolphin

I'm running Fedora 23 Server on one machine, and Fedora KDE Spin on another. These are both very recent installs. I previously ran Ubuntu Server and Windows, and connected the two using a samba share. Since I'm now running Linux on both machines, I thought it would be a good idea to switch to an NFS connection.

Everything's set up on the server side properly. I can connect using the command line, creating a directory and mounting it. But when I try accessing it using the Dolphin file manager, as I should, I get this message:

```
Could not mount device.
The reported error was:
Failed to mount /home/blackwidower, /var/www/html
```

I've tried running Dolphin as root (sudo dolphin) but that gives me a different, 'access denied' error. And it isn't what I want, anyway.

What exactly do I need to do to get this to work? Should this not be handled automatically?